# Behaviour of stored procedures when called from a task

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, error-handling, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to use a stored procedure to insert to a log table (along with some other functionality that isn't relevant). This procedure needs to be called automatically by a task, execute some code, then write to a table. I can do all of the above, however when I include a try/catch block for error handling the procedure wont update the log tables.

**Minimal working example:**

Creating the log table and procedure to write to it,

```
create or replace table test_log_table (
  PROC_NAME VARCHAR, 
  MESSAGE VARCHAR,
  TIME TIMESTAMP
   );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_SP_TEST(TRGT_TABLE VARCHAR, MESSAGE VARCHAR)
RETURNS  VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$  
    const PROC_NAME = Object.keys(this)[0]; // name of executing procedure
    
    insert_sql =
    `INSERT INTO ` + TRGT_TABLE+`
    (
      PROC_NAME, 
      MESSAGE,
      TIME
    )
    VALUES
    ('`+ PROC_NAME +`','`+MESSAGE+`', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());` 
    
    try{col_list_fetch_trgt = snowflake.execute(
        { sqlText: insert_sql })
    }
    catch(err){
        return "failed: "+err
    }
$$;
```

When calling the procedure manually it all behaves as expected

```
call log_sp_test('test_log_table', 'calling manually');
select * from test_log_table;
```

The select * returns the following table

| PROC_NAME | MESSAGE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOG_SP_TEST | calling manually | 2022-01-28 09:26:22.791 |

Now we create a task and call the procedure again automatically

```
-- now test calling this proc using a task
create task mytask_minute
  warehouse = COMPUTE_WH
  schedule = '1 minute'
as
  call log_sp_test('test_log_table', 'calling via trigger');
  
alter task mytask_minute resume;
show tasks;

-- can then check when a task is next due to run by
select timestampdiff(second, current_timestamp, scheduled_time) as next_run, scheduled_time, current_timestamp, name, state 
from table(information_schema.task_history()) where state = 'SCHEDULED' order by completed_time desc;

select * from test_log_table;
alter task mytask_minute suspend;
show tasks;
```

The select * statement still returns the same

| PROC_NAME | MESSAGE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOG_SP_TEST | calling manually | 2022-01-28 09:26:22.791 |

Whilst if we remove the try/catch block in the procedure we get the expected

| PROC_NAME | MESSAGE | TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| LOG_SP_TEST | calling manually | 2022-01-28 09:26:22.791 |
| LOG_SP_TEST | calling via trigger | 2022-01-28 09:33:21.881 |

How can I call this procedure automatically whilst still being able to write to a log table and properly handle errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

- using `;` at end of the line
- using parameters instead of concatenation
- calling procedure with schema name 'PUBLIC.test_log_table'

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LOG_SP_TEST(TRGT_TABLE VARCHAR, MESSAGE VARCHAR)
RETURNS  VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$  
    const PROC_NAME = Object.keys(this)[0]; // name of executing procedure
    
    insert_sql = `INSERT INTO IDENTIFIER(?) ( PROC_NAME,  MESSAGE, TIME)
                 VALUES(?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());`;
    
    try{
      col_list_fetch_trgt = snowflake.execute(
        { sqlText: insert_sql, binds:[TRGT_TABLE, PROC_NAME, MESSAGE] });
    }
    catch(err){
        return "failed: "+err
    }
$$;
```

Task:

```
create OR REPLACE task mytask_minute
  warehouse = COMPUTE_WH
  schedule = '1 minute'
as
  call PUBLIC.log_sp_test('PUBLIC.test_log_table', 'calling via trigger');
```

Output:

[image]